# После сборки react-native приложения получаю java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: couldn't find DSO to load: libhermes.so

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

Сделал простое тестовое приложение с выводом текста, на эмуляторе или в вебе всё отображается, все ок, но на реальном устройстве:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: couldn't find DSO to load: libhermes.so
```

Устанавливаю проект через `expo`, потом собираю его на `expo.dev`, из `AAB`, перевожу в `APKS` и вынимаю оттуда апк. Что я делаю неправильно? Что-то понять не могу.

```
            java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: couldn't find DSO to load: libhermes.so
    SoSource 0: com.facebook.soloader.DirectorySoSource[root = /data/app/~~-WuyB5lHPPEsHjn7AFTBLg==/com.tignari2221.android2-gdUfc2ySoUxcP-NVb5rH9A==/lib/arm64 flags = 0]
    SoSource 1: com.facebook.soloader.DirectApkSoSource[root = [/data/app/~~-WuyB5lHPPEsHjn7AFTBLg==/com.tignari2221.android2-gdUfc2ySoUxcP-NVb5rH9A==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a]]
    SoSource 2: com.facebook.soloader.DirectorySoSource[root = /system/lib64 flags = 2]
    SoSource 3: com.facebook.soloader.DirectorySoSource[root = /vendor/lib64 flags = 2]
    Native lib dir: /data/app/~~-WuyB5lHPPEsHjn7AFTBLg==/com.tignari2221.android2-gdUfc2ySoUxcP-NVb5rH9A==/lib/arm64
 result: 0
    at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.doLoadLibraryBySoName(SoLoader.java:1228)
    at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibraryBySoNameImpl(SoLoader.java:1044)
    at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibraryBySoName(SoLoader.java:956)
    at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibrary(SoLoader.java:903)
    at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibrary(SoLoader.java:869)
    at com.facebook.hermes.reactexecutor.HermesExecutor.loadLibrary(HermesExecutor.java:26)
    at com.facebook.hermes.reactexecutor.HermesExecutor.<clinit>(HermesExecutor.java:20)
    at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManagerBuilder.getDefaultJSExecutorFactory(ReactInstanceManagerBuilder.java:379)
    at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManagerBuilder.build(ReactInstanceManagerBuilder.java:325)
    at com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost.createReactInstanceManager(ReactNativeHost.java:96)
    at expo.modules.ReactNativeHostWrapperBase.createReactInstanceManager(ReactNativeHostWrapperBase.kt:32)
    at com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost.getReactInstanceManager(ReactNativeHost.java:42)
    at com.tignari2221.android2.MainApplication.onCreate(MainApplication.java:71)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1211)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:7062)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:271)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2125)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:210)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:299)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8250)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:556)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1045)
```

Comment: Добавил в app.json "hermesEnabled": true и ничего не поменялось